# why this code wont work

Tags: asp.net, mysql

i have set a an editor to enter its content into the database and then i can retrive and edit it and save it again and here is what i used:

```
string user = Page.User.Identity.Name;

    MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(@"connection string;");
    MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("UPDATE copy SET cv='" + '"' + Editor1.Content.Replace("'", "''") + '"' + "' WHERE id = '" + user + "' ", conn);

    conn.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

    conn.Close();
```

**inserting and select works fine but update doesn't , it doesnt give errors but it just doesnt change the content(no matter what i change it always remains the same content);**

***i know that this is open to sql injection and i should switch to parametrized query and i will do just that after things work***

*i am using asp.net 3.5, mysql 5.0*

**i have identified the problem and making a new question with it 
thank you all for your help**

Comment: Huh... Smelling [code injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_injection#SQL_injection) aren't we?

Comment: please , put a break point and tell me if the `Editor1.Content`is the updated value you want, and tell me the value of ``user`.

Comment: @just_name i tried a break point and for some reason the content of the editor is always empty although it has content

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does not matter why it doesn't work, it's just plain wrong.

You're wide open to [SQL injection attacks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_injection#SQL_injection), and that should be your first concern.

You fix that by using parameters instead, something like this:

```
MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("UPDATE copy SET cv=?cv WHERE id = ?id", conn);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("cv", Editor1.Content);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("id", user);
```

Comment: thank you i actually am going to switch to parametrized query but after i get things working

Comment: Are you actually using the connection string as shown? ie. *inside* the string?

Comment: Why don't you try the parameterized way now and see if that doesn't also magically fix your problems?

Comment: no the "connection string" is replaced with the actual one and that one is tested, and ok i will give it a try

Comment: Are you getting any errors, exceptions, whatnot? Also, what does ExecuteNonQuery return? It should return the number of rows modified. Does it return 0, or 1, or what?

Comment: If it returns 1, it updated a record. Are you sure you're looking at the right rows?

Answer (score 0):

ExecuteNonQuery should return number of rows effected, with this in mind you can debug the code. for us to help can you write the sql statment that you are producing in string?

besides this first thing that comes to mind is that the id = 'user' might not be right, id suggests a integer but name looks like it is a string value.

Comment: the user name is right as i am using it to retrieve content from the database